# how can i create a active drop down list menu in css

Tags: css

how can I create a active drop down list menu in css like the one here: http://jaamericas.org/programas-educativos/programas-de-primaria#ja-nosotros-mismos

please Help I am new stack-overflow, but been using it for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to create buttons dropbdown menus. More info: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden divs and use javascript to show them onMouseOver

```
<a href=index.html onMouseOver="showDiv" onMouseOut="hideDiv">

<div id="showMe">link</div>

<style type="text/css">
#showMe { display: none }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(){
    document.getelementbyid("showMe").style.display = block;
}
function showDiv(){
    document.getelementbyid("showMe").style.display = none;
}
```